# IBM RAD (Rational Application Developer 8 (8.0.3)) and WebSphere 6.1 - endless publishing unstoppable nightmare

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

Did anybody try to work with WAS 6.1 in RAD 8.0? I have a problem that makes it almost impossible to work. All the time I am trying to work, RAD publishes to WebSphere, though I have setting "Never publish automatically" in server details. Because of this it is also impossible to debug, and also very often WebSphere changes its status to "Stopped" though I hasn't stopped it. I set up fix pack 6.1.0-WS-WASSDK-WinX32-FP0000041.pak on my websphere, but it didn't help. I didn't have this problem with RAD 7.5.5 on the same WebSphere, so there is something wrong with RAD 8.0 when it works with WAS 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

I use RAD 8.0.3 with WAS 6.1. I have seen at times the application restarting out from underneath me in ways that confuse it, but I've also had it work fine at other times.

When the former is happening, it's usually because I'm making a lot of changes in quick succession and don't actually want to re-test until they're all finished, so I just stop the server for a while.

I haven't tried the "Never publish" setting you describe, so I can't add to your knowledge of whether that can actually work. Another thing you might try is the "If server is started, publish changes immediately" checkbox in the "Add and Remove..." dialog.

Comment: Thank you dbreaux, I made setting "automatically publish when resources change" and after that I didn't see the problem. So 2 steps that solved my problem where 1) setting up fix pack 6.1.0-WS-WAS-WinX32-FP0000041.pak + 6.1.0-WS-WASSDK-WinX32-FP0000041.pak 2) setting "automatically publish when resources change" in server details

Answer (score 1):

Thank you dbreaux, I made setting "automatically publish after a build event" and after that I didn't see the problem, though it seems strange. So 2 steps that solved my problem were

1. setting up fix pack 6.1.0-WS-WAS-WinX32-FP0000041.pak + 6.1.0-WS-WASSDK-WinX32-FP0000041.pak
2. setting "automatically publish after a build event" in server details

Answer (score 0):

The post below looks to be on point, at least for the current version of Rapid Application Developer (9.1.1).  The problems I was experiencing were

- For my local server it seemed like it was still "semi" publishing.  I suspect but have not yet verified that changing "Run server with resources within workspace" to "Run server with resources on server" in the Server Overview page will fix that.
- For my remote server it seemed like it was publishing every morning when I connected.  The post referred me to the setting in Preferences..Server..Launching..Automatically publish when starting servers.

[Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21306325) is the post.